# quando a altura e exibida na tela ela fica desta forma 165.0 e eu queria que exibi-se desta forma 1.65

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

package testarpessoa;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pessoa {
     private String nome;
    private int dia;
    private int mes;
    private int ano;
    private double altura;
    private int idade;

```
 // Construtor
 /*public  testarPessoa(int Dia, int Mes, int Ano){

   Dia = dia;
   Mes = mes;
   Ano = ano;
}*/


//Set Nome, altura
public void setNome(String nome){
    this.nome = nome;

}
public void setAltura(double altura){
    this.altura = altura;
}

//  Set Data
public void setDia(int dia){
    this.dia = dia;
}
public void setMes(int mes){
    this.mes = mes;
}
public void setAno(int ano){
    this.ano = ano;
}

// Get Data
public int getdia(){
    return dia;
}
public int getmes(){
    return mes;
}
public int getano(){
    return ano;
}

//Get Nome Altura
public String getnome(){
    return nome;
}
public double getaltura(){
    return altura;
```

}
    // Impresão de tela 
    public void dadosPessoa(){
System.out.println("NOME ---> " + nome);
System.out.println ("ALTURA ---> "  + altura);
System.out.println("IDADE ---> " + idade);
    }

```
public void cadastrarPessoa(){

    Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out. println("Digite o nome: ");
    nome = ler.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Digite sua Altura: ");
    altura = ler.nextDouble();
}
```

}

Comment: É pura matemática, não entendo porque as pessoas acham que precisam fazer algo mais sofisticado que dividir por 100.

Comment: exatamente estava tão pilhado em algum comando que acabei esquecendo da matemática simples